# AppEngine Static Files with Express/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine

I'm trying to serve a static application as well as an API through express on AppEngine. Hitting app.com/* should take you to the public directory, but app.com/v1/ should hit the endpont.

My issue is that the [code in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/serving-static-files) doesn't seem to be working for me, even when I disable express entirely.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
app
--src
---v1
--public
---index.html
--app.yaml
```

But placing this in the yaml (ignoring the API for now)

```
handlers:
  - url: /static
      static_dir: public
  - url: /.*
      secure: always
      redirect_http_response_code: 301
      script: auto
```

Returns 502 when I visit the app.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, could you please share the logs of your app in Stackdriver Logging when requesting `app.com/`? This might me related to a coding issue, lest start to discard possibilities.

Comment: Hi! No warnings/errors on stackdriver, just 502 response when trying to access files that should be in that public directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a quick start following the documentation you shared, and just added the following entry to the `app.yaml`

`handlers:
  - url: /static
      static_dir: public
  -url: /(.*)
      static_files: public/\1
      upload: public/(.*)
  - url: /.*
      secure: always
      redirect_http_response_code: 301
      script: auto`

Then, tried with https://xxxx.appspot.com/index.html.